# Filtering foreign Key content in django templated using if statement

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have two models with one being a foreign key to another. A user can only submit an answer. am trying to use the if statement to check if an answer exit for a user then the submit answer button should change the update button the template.

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_or_level = models.ForeignKey(StudentClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='assignment', blank=True, null=True)
    Text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_expire = models.DateTimeField()


class Answer(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='assignment')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My View

```
class AssignmentView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'assignment.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_couses'
    now = timezone.now()
    queryset = Course.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        context = super(AssignmentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'assignment_list': Assignment.objects.filter(class_or_level=self.request.user.student.class_or_level, date_expire__gte=now).order_by('-date_expire'),
        })
        return context
```

this the template> What the users submitted answer to show if he does submit one else show the form like to submit answer

```
{% for assignment in assignment_list %}
<h4>{{  assignment.title|truncatewords:12 }}</h4>
 {% if assignment.answer %}
{{  assignment.answer.file }}
  <button> <a href="">Update Answer</a></button>
    {% else %}
      <button> <a href="">Summit Answer</a></button>
{% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: According to the models an assignment can have multiple answers but you're expecting only one answer in the assignment, is that right?

Comment: @arthursribeiro every student can give only one answer. I want to show the students answer in the template if they have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your view or create a template tag to identify if an assignment has a response of a specific user, I decided to change the view and add a new variable to the assignment object that will have the information of if the user who requested the page has an answer to that assignment:

```py
class AssignmentView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'assignment.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_couses'
    now = timezone.now()
    queryset = Course.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        context = super(AssignmentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        assignment_list = Assignment.objects.filter(
            class_or_level=self.request.user.student.class_or_level,
            date_expire__gte=now
        ).order_by('-date_expire')

        for assignment in assignment_list:
            try:
                assignment.student_answer = Answer.objects.get(
                    assignment=assignment,
                    student=self.request.user
                )
            except Answer.DoesNotExist:
                pass

        context.update({
            'assignment_list': assignment_list,
        })
        return context
```

Then, inside of your template you can do the following:

```
{% for assignment in assignment_list %}
    <h4>{{  assignment.title|truncatewords:12 }}</h4>
    {% if assignment.student_answer %}
        {{ assignment.student_answer.file }}
        <button> <a href="">Update Answer</a></button>
    {% else %}
        <button> <a href="">Summit Answer</a></button>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

By doing that you'll achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: please I still have a problem. There are multiple users that need to submit their individual answer to an assignment. and every individual must submit only one answer to an assignment. What I what is that if a user has not submitted an  answer to an assignment the submit answer is shown if he as submitted the answer is shown in the template

Comment: @Yenji Do you have the view code so I can post a more complete solution for you?

Comment: I added the view now. Am using ListView

Comment: @Yenji I updated the answer, I think you'll have what you're looking for now.